# Changing the voice of a sentence

Tags: passive-voice

Change the voice of "That too many cooks spoil the broth is known to all."

Which is correct

> 1. All know that too many cooks spoil the broth

OR

> 2. All know that the broth is spoilt by too many cooks

Comment: Starting with "All know" is not usual (*all* being used as a noun). I would use "Everyone knows".

Comment: It's known to everybody/all that the broth is spoilt by too many cooks.

Comment: @user3169 - It's a little poetic, but starting "All <verb>" isn't that strange.  I think a lot of people would be familiar with the phrasing from the verse ["All have sinned, and come short of the glory of God..."](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans+3:23&version=KJV)

Comment: @stangdon I meant starting with "All know" specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Both are fully grammatical (though a bit strained).

The original sentence has two finite verbs, the main one ('is known') and the subordinate one ('spoil').

'Is known' is passive, so changing the voice of the main clause gives you your no. 1.

The verb in the "that"-claus, "spoil", is active, so changing the voice of that gives you your no. 2.

What answer the question wanted is anybody's guess: it's a badly worded question.

Comment: +1...Don't forget choice #4, in which both verbs are put in the passive voice: _"That the broth **is spoilt** by too many cooks **is known** to all."_